# Typescript cannot set property of undefined

Tags: typescript

Can someone please explain why you can't do this in Typescript?

```
this.obj.id = 1;
this.obj.str = 'This is string';
```

But you can do this:

```
this.obj = { id: 1, str: 'This is string'};
```

Comment: What is `this.obj` initially? If you didn't define it, you're trying to define properties on something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Because you cannot set property of `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of you can't do but, you're doing it wrong.
See [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6lma2j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I was able to define by using it like this:

```js
obj = [];
obj2 = { id: 0, str: '' };
  
this.obj = { id: 1, str: 'This is string' };
this.obj2.id = 1;
this.obj2.str = 'This is string';
console.log(this.obj)
console.log(this.obj2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I already know why. You cannot set property of undefined. So you should initialize a default value or empty value.